# How to Migrate from Hibernate Validator Legacy (3.x) to Hibernate Validator 4.x

Tags: hibernate-validator

Our application was built using Hibernate Validator 3.1.0 (now called Hibernate Validator Legacy).

I'd like to migrate it to use Hibernate Validator 4.x (4.2.0).

I can't seem to find any documentation on the approach to migrating an application from using 3.x to 4.x.  It's mentioned in certain places, but I can't find any useful information whatsoever.  It's as if the creators of 4.x just left everyone on 3.x dangling.

Can anyone provide some useful information or links on the process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Situation is still more or less as you described. Best available document seems to be [JBOSS AS migration document](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7#HowdoImigratemyapplicationfromAS5orAS6toAS7-MigratetoHibernate4Validator), and that is not much.

Comment: Link with anchor to Validator section https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7#HowdoImigratemyapplicationfromAS5orAS6toAS7-MigratetoHibernate4Validator

Comment: @Hardy Thanks, but that is exactly same link.